# Where can I add attributes to the generated script tags before building my Vue app?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, build, vuejs2

I want to add attributes to the script tags that are generated when my Webpack Vue app is build. 
I can't seem to find the file where I can add them before building the script so they always get added on building my app.

Are these options present?

Thanks!

This is my index file after build right now:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<meta name=viewport content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
<title>nes_b2c_koffieplein_anchor-nav</title>
<link href=./static/css/app.bfaa53c28fee7adbfa6730ae0381661b.css 
rel=stylesheet>
</head>

<body>
<div id=achor-links></div>
<script type=text/javascript 
src=./static/js/manifest.3ad1d5771e9b13dbdad2.js></script>
<script type=text/javascript 
src=./static/js/vendor.a73abbfdb077dea7910a.js></script>
<script type=text/javascript 
src=./static/js/app.77c072c52113ea3ac052.js></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Where are these scripts generated within my Vue files?

Comment: They are generated by [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/), I assume you used the Vue Cli to generate your project?

Comment: Yes indeed, I assumed webpack generated them, but can't seem to find the option to add attributes on building in the webpack config files.

Comment: [Maybe this can be of help?](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#html) try to modify `public/index.html`

Answer (score 1):

I dowloaded https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin and https://www.npmjs.com/package/script-ext-html-webpack-plugin.

Followed the documentation and got it working.