# Is it possible to add an attribute to a script loaded by nuxt

Tags: html, vue.js, webpack, nuxt.js

Is it possible to add an attribute to a script loaded by nuxt?

[image: scripts loaded by nuxt]

Background: i need to add an attribute, so that Cookiebot(https://www.cookiebot.com/en/) does ignores my script. Right know it blocks a few, that sends client side Requests.

Comment: Under the hood vue uses webpack to generate the files, Try the answer in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51649065/

Comment: I couldnt find a way to add the attribute to all script chunks. But after i used the proxy module for all axios requests, instead of sending them to the seperate backend domain, cookiebot stopped blocking that script.

Comment: @David I just ran into a similar issue with nuxt and cookiebot. For me the page broke because some nuxt scripts were blocked by cookiebot auto-mode. Reclassifying the cookies in that script (in my case "i18n_redirected") as essential cookies got the page running again without any changes to my code

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a late answer, but was looking for this myself. It's simple with Nuxt3.

In nuxt.config.ts, define each script tag with its attributes as properties:

```
meta: {
  title: 'Page Title',
  meta: [
    { charset: 'utf-8' },
    { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
  ],  
  {
    hid: 'cookiebot',
    id: 'Cookiebot',
    src: 'https://consent.cookiebot.com/uc.js',
    'data-cbid': 'xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx',
    'data-blockingmode': 'auto',
    type: 'text/javascript'
  }
}
```

Read more in the documentation: https://v3.nuxtjs.org/getting-started/seo-meta/#meta-components